# Update Object or Create it if it doesn't exists?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Im digging though some cloud code to do some manipulation of data and save it as a new class.

I have a situation where I read a row from another class, do some math functions, then save the manipulated data to another class which is then read by our client.

The problem is that If the other object already exists in the new class, I just want to update it instead of creating a new one.  I know in the parse documentation
it lists creating an object and updating but not really functionality to update if exists, and if not create.

Here is just some example code.. the out data is the data prepped to save for the new class.  I can crate the new class object, but when I update some value that 
should trigger a update instead of a create new is where things fall apart.

Please understand JS is not my first language so this might be hacked or completely going about it the wrong way, but I should stress I do not know the objectId of
the new class.

```
if(out.length > 0) {   

  var game = Parse.Object.extend("Gamers");
  var query = new Parse.Query(game);
  query.equalTo("playername", player);  // using this to find the player since I dont have the objectid
  query.find({                       
    success: function(results) {

    // Successfully retrieved the object.
    if (results && results.length == "1") {

      var playerObjectId = results[0].id
      /// save only updated data to the local class ????

    } else {
      // no results, create a new local
      console.log('no results')

      // save as a new object
      var gamers = new game();

      gamers.set("somevalue", somevalue);
      gamers.set("somevalue2", somevalue2);

      gamers.save(null, {
        success: function(gamers) {
          // Execute any logic that should take place after the object is saved.
          console.log('New object created with objectId: ' + gamers.id);
        },
        error: function(gamers, error) {
          // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
          // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
          console.log('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.message);
        }
      });                    
    }

  },
  error: function(error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
});

} else {
console.log('array is empty, something went wrong')
 //this array is empty
}
```

Comment: what do you ask?
how to update the object that have the id == playerObjectId?

Comment: Whats with the down votes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A create or update function has three distinct bits: find, update, or possibly create.  Lets build the three separately.

```
function findGamerWithName(name) {
    var game = Parse.Object.extend("Gamers");
    query.equalTo("playername", name);
    return query.find();
}

function updateGamer(gamer, someValue, someValue2) {
    gamer.set("somevalue", someValue);
    gamer.set("somevalue2", someValue2);
    return gamer.save();
}     

function createGamer(someValue, someValue2) {
    var Gamer = Parse.Object.extend("Gamers");
    var gamer = new Gamer();
    return updateGamer(gamer, someValue, someValue2); 
}
```

Now we can understand and test these separately (you should test them).  And now, it's easy to write create or update logic...

```
function createOrUpdateGamer(name, someValue, someValue2) {
    return findGamerWithName(name).then(function(gamer) {
        return (gamer)? updateGamer(gamer, someValue, someValue2) : createGamer(someValue, someValue2);
    });
}
```